# How to create an ArrayList from a dialog box in JavaFX?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

Hello having trouble creating an array from a dialog box. I am able to type in the dialog and print out index [0] of ArrayList. But when I press Ok it restarts and replaces index [0] instead of adding to the ArrayList . How do I get the application to keep running instead of restarting?

Original Assignment:

> Going back to the GUI assignment. You can modify this to use JavaFX
>   if you want to.
>
> Create an application that has a button that has “Enter your info.” 
>   When clicked it will present a JDialog that has labels and text boxes
>   that allow the user to enter their name, email, and phone number.  The
>   JDialog will have buttons OK and Cancel.
>
> When the user clicks Cancel, the dialog will go away without doing
>   anything else.
>
> When the user clicks OK, the user’s information will be extracted from
>   the dialog, and dumped out on the console. Notice that you only are
>   listening for Click events. We will add to that spec.
>
> Define a class to hold the info for a single person.  Declare an
>   ArrayList of this type.  When the user clicks OK, extract the info
>   from the dialog.  This time, pass the info to the constructor method
>   of your class that will hold the info.  Add this newly created object
>   to your array list.
>
> Using an enhanced for loop, dump the ArrayList onto the console.
>
> Add several user info's to the ArrayList, each time, dumping the
>   entire list to the console.
>
> Sort the ArrayList. Dump the ArrayList onto the console.

```
public class UsefulGUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Enter your info");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                dialogBox();
            }
        });

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Useful GUI");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public class User {
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private String phone;

        public User(String n, String e, String p) {
            this.name = n;
            this.email = e;
            this.phone = p;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Name: " + name + " Email: " + email + " Phone: " + phone;
        }
    }
    public void dialogBox() {
        Dialog<User> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        ArrayList<User>list = new ArrayList<User>();


        dialog.setTitle("User info");

        Label name = new Label("Name: ");
        Label email = new Label("Email: ");
        Label phone = new Label("Phone: ");
        TextField textName = new TextField();
        TextField textEmail = new TextField();
        TextField textPhone = new TextField();

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.add(name, 1, 1);
        grid.add(textName, 2, 1);
        grid.add(email, 1, 2);
        grid.add(textEmail, 2, 2);
        grid.add(phone, 1, 3);
        grid.add(textPhone, 2, 3);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

        ButtonType buttonType = new ButtonType("Ok", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        dialog.setResultConverter(new Callback<ButtonType, User>() {
            @Override
            public User call(ButtonType b) {
                if (b == buttonType) {
                    return new User(textName.getText(), textEmail.getText(), textPhone.getText());
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        Optional<User>info = dialog.showAndWait();

        // Adds user to list
        list.add(new User(textName.getText(), textEmail.getText(), textPhone.getText()));
        System.out.print("Info Added.\n NEWUSER ");
        System.out.println(new User(textName.getText(), textEmail.getText(), textPhone.getText()));

        //Collections.sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + list.get(i));
        }

        //if (info.isPresent()) {
        //  System.out.println(info.get());
        //}
    }
    public void quitApplication() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Dialog<User> dialog = new Dialog<>();`?

Comment: `ArrayList<User>list = new ArrayList<User>();` needs to be global.

Comment: [JavaFX Dialogs](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) - expand on the Text Input Dialog example

Comment: In your `results.isPresent()` you need to have something like`list.add(new User(textName.getText(), textEmail.getText(), textPhone.getText());`